# How to read "interfaces" map of json without defining structure in Golang?

Tags: json, go

Following [this tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/parsing-json-with-golang/) I'm trying to read a json file in Golang. It says there are two ways of doing that:

1. unmarshal the JSON using a set of predefined structs
2. or unmarshal the JSON using a map[string]interface{}

Since I'll probably have a lot of different json formats I prefer to interpret it on the fly. So I now have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    // Open our jsonFile
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("users.json")
    // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened users.json")
    // defer the closing of our jsonFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    var result map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &result)

    fmt.Println(result["users"])
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", result["users"])
}
```

This prints out:

```
Successfully Opened users.json
[map[type:Reader age:23 social:map[facebook:https://facebook.com twitter:https://twitter.com] name:Elliot] map[name:Fraser type:Author age:17 social:map[facebook:https://facebook.com twitter:https://twitter.com]]]
[]interface {}
```

At this point I don't understand how I can read the age of the first user (23). I tried some variations:

```
fmt.Println(result["users"][0])
fmt.Println(result["users"][0].age)
```

But apparently, `type interface {} does not support indexing`.

Is there a way that I can access the items in the json without defining the structure?

Comment: If you know enough about your JSON to parse it this way, you know enough to use predefined structs. This is almost always the preferred way.

Comment: @Flimzy - `"almost always the preferred way"` => But why? If it's possible without, then why define it? Or is it not possible without defining it? Or are there big advantages to actually define it? And if so, what are they?

Comment: Because it's immensely easier to use a predefined struct, as you are discovering.  But then if you like `result["users"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{}).["age"]`), far be it from me to dissuade you from overly verbose, difficult-to-read code. :)

Comment: What it really boils down to: Go is a strictly typed language. This means you _must_ use strict types, even with JSON. You can do this one of two-ways: With compile-time types, as defined in custom structs, or with runtime reflection. Both require you to "get to" the static type. Doing it at compile time is much more efficient (thus faster), and far easier to read. So only use reflection when you must.

Comment: @Flimzy - Thanks for explaining the why. I guess the way to go would be simply defining it then.

Comment: @Flimzy - By the way, I tried your suggestion, and it gives me `./main.go:54:74: syntax error: unexpected [, expecting name or (`. That refers to the last usae of `[`, the one surrounding `"age"`. Any other ideas?

Comment: That was meant as an example, not a specific suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want

```
fmt.Println(result["users"].(map[string]interface{})["age"])
```

or

```
fmt.Println(result[0].(map[string]interface{})["age"])
```

As the JSON is a map of maps the type of the leaf nodes is interface{} and so has to be converted to map[string]interface{} in order to lookup a key

Defining a struct is much easier.  My top tip for doing this is to use a website that converts JSON to a Go struct definition, like [Json-To-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/)

Comment: The first one gives a `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}` and the second one gives a `cannot use 0 (type int) as type string in map index`. Any other ideas?